# Plotting the airy disk pattern in MATLAB

Tags: bessel-functions

So the formula for the airy pattern is

[image: source: wikipedia]

with J being the Bessel function `besselj(1,x)` in MatLab. How would i plot this and approximate it for just the x values of 0-10?

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [0:0.1:10]; % kasin(phi)
I0 = 1;
I = I0*(2*besselj(1,x)./x).^2
plot(x,I)
```

Comment: It's best to accompany code with an explanation as to what it does.